# Asp.net MVC 4 - Getting 404 error when requesting a valid controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting a 404 error when requesting a valid controller action. Other actions in the same controller are working. I've tried renaming the action, but to no avail. You will see that I am redirecting to a view with a different name, but when I tried to just do a normal return View(model), that also ended up in a 404. When debugging, the controller is never hit. I ran a route debug and that looks fine. I am using the out-of-the-box route config.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am at a complete loss at this point. Anyone brainiacs out there? Much appreciated!

Comment: Why your controller is `Create` but your view is `Edit`? Is that intentional?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the action? Is it possible that the `return HttpNotFound();` is getting hit?

Comment: Yes. I meant to do that. But I have also tried simply return View(model) with the same problem. When debugging the controller is never reached.

Comment: Actually Thr33Dii, you are correct! I cannot beleive I did not see that. The hazards of copy and paste. Please post that as the answer and I will credit you. Thanks again! Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the action? Is it possible that the `return HttpNotFound();` is getting hit?

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, it turned out to be a incorrect namespace because I had moved the controller to a different area.